# logic app 'When a resource event occurs' won't trigger

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps, azure-eventhub, azure-triggers

I have a blob storage that has 2 Containers called input and output. when a file gets uploaded to input then a Function app (Blobtrigger) would work on it and save the result in output folder.
right now i need to trigger a workflow in Azure logic app. i didn't created any event grid outside of this workflow and now i'm trying to trigger it when a file get's uploaded (Created) in the output container.
However my app won't trigger. what should i do?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it.
Make sure your Storage Account is Version 2.(it's really important check it)

mine was V1 so i had to change it here:

[image]

use this as a filter for your specific Container. (for more Info Check [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-event-overview?WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5003556#filtering-events))

```
/blobServices/default/containers/MyContainer/
```

in my Case it would be:

```
/blobServices/default/containers/output/
```

Answer (score 0):

***I have reproduced in my environment and triggered an event when blob get uploaded and it got triggered:***

***Please find the below approach to fix your issue :***

[image]

***Then uploaded a blob like below:***

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

[image]

***EDIT:***
***I too Uploaded into SubFolder:***

[image]

***Then in Ouput Subfolder:***

[image]

Comment: i'm uplaoding to a sub folder that's why i have output there. 
i just want to trigger when a blob is uploaded in the Output container. i used it like this Containername/{name}

Comment: I edited my answer, Can you please look into that.

Comment: that works but the problem is, as i said in the Question, there are 2 container and i want to trigger ONLY when filles were uplaoded in output (the other one is input). with your approach it will get trigger when the files get's uplaoded in my input container