# How to trigger an event-triggered function in azure when a blob is create

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-eventgrid

I created an event-triggered function in Azure (name of the function app: "stamevents", name of the function: "EventGridTrigger1".
this is my function.json file:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is my init.py file:

```
import json
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(event: func.EventGridEvent):
    result = json.dumps({
        'id': event.id,
        'data': event.get_json(),
        'topic': event.topic,
        'subject': event.subject,
        'event_type': event.event_type,
    })

    logging.info('Python EventGrid trigger processed an event: %s', result)
```

Now, I want to trigger this function when I'm uploading a blob.
So I went to my storage account, pressed on "Events" and chose "Azure Function".
[image]
and create.

Next I chose the function app and the function I just created

But this is what I see and I don't understand what to do next, and how to make this function fire after I upload a blob.

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Plz check this link to associate blog storage trigger to an Azure function - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp

Comment: @Gandhi, I'm not looking for a blob trigger but for an event trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced in my environment and i got expected results. I followed this workaround:
You can use **Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated**  as below in using azure functions:

[image]

Click on Azure functions in end point type then click on end point as below:

[image]

Upload a blob like below:

[image]

After uploading blob check the logs of event grid function app as below, you will get to know it has executed and event grid got triggered as below:

[image]

You can use Logics apps for triggering an event when a blob is created as below:

[image]

And when i upload a blob like below it runs and gets triggered as below:

[image]

Now when you check the run history it trigered as below:

[image]

And you can check as below:

[image]

So, in last you can check the events i created as below:

[image]

Comment: Hey, Thank you, super helpful! How do I connect only a specific storage account or even a specific container to the blobCreated event?

Comment: Please refer [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73360708/logic-app-when-a-resource-event-occurs-wont-trigger) for specific container which I and Op answered.

Comment: Can we please have a quick call? I'll be happy to pay you for your help... my mail is stam.analysis@gmail.com, can you please contact me?